# Java Hibernate MariaDB DDL execution

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

I am deploying a web application from a windows machine to a debian server running MariaDB 10.1.26 (everything works on the dev machine). Problem is that some of the DDLs are not executed. The class in question is the user class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    private String passwordHash;


  }
```

The hibernate properties I used are:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

And the error I am getting is this:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I assume this happens because of the UUID key. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the below solutions.

Solution 1 :

Add Dialect using below line of code in your hibernate configuration file.

`<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect</property>`

Solution 2 :

We get this error when try to create JPA entity with the name "User" (Mariadb) which may be reserved.
We can resolve this by changing the table name by @Table annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {..}
```

Or change the table name manually.